# Allow both upper case and lower case inside ng-if

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have condition like this

```
<table   ng-if="name=='john' && name=='MARK'">
//rest of the code
</table>
```

My code will execute when ng-if is true.

Now my doubt is , ng-if should be true even when name is in both upper and lower case..

```
<table   ng-if="name=='JOhN' && name=='maRK'">
    //rest of the code
    </table>
```

Is it possible?
I have tried this using `if-else` condition also.

```
if(name.toString()='john'){
alert('success')
}
else{
alert('failure')
}
```

Is it correct?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

try,

```
<table   ng-if="name.toLowerCase()=='john' && name.toLowerCase()=='mark'">
//rest of the code
</table>
```

or with angular `lowercase` filter

```
<table   ng-if="(name| lowercase) =='john' && (name | lowercase)=='mark'">
   //rest of the code
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

I know this has been answered and accetped but I would do it with a function and then return the result of checking the name given with an array of accepted names. This way - it is easier to change the names in the future or to add other names as required.

```
//html
<table   ng-if="checkName(name)">
   //rest of the code
</table>


//js 
checkName(name){
  let acceptedNames = ['john','mark'];
  let nameStr = name.lowerCase();
  let result = false;
  if(acceptedNames.indexOf(nameStr) > -1 ){result = true};
  return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Better way to do is to convert both values to same case using the filter **`| uppercase)`**  and do comparision

Answer (score 0):

Use the lowercase or uppercase pipe to match the condition

```
ng-if="name.toLowerCase()=='john'"
```

This is the easiest way to acheive the ng if condition